# Why is VS Code/TypeScript ignoring my type assertion?

Tags: typescript

I've made a type assertion, but it's being ignored:

[image: vscode_screenshot]

When I hover over my `orderQuery` variable it should tell me that the type is `QueryBuilderType<Model>` because I've asserted that this is the type by writing `as QueryBuilderType<Model>` in the assignment.

What am I missing? Why doesn't this work as I imagine it should work?

Answer (score 0):

> When I hover over my orderQuery variable it should tell me that the type is QueryBuilderType because I've asserted that this is the type by writing as QueryBuilderType in the assignment.

Most likely `QueryBuilderType<Model>` is resolving to `any`!

## More

Here is another simplified/reproducible example that does the same:

```
type QueryBuilderType<T> = any;
type Model = {}
const something = 123;

const orderQuery = something as QueryBuilderType<Model>;
```

[image]